# OpendTect 6.2.0 bad installation in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x64

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

Some days ago I were trying to install [OpendTect](https://dgbes.com/index.php/download) in Ubuntu, I have the *.sh* OpendTect installer for linux.

I did run:

```
chmod a+x OpendTect_Installer_lux32.sh
./OpendTect_Installer_lux64.sh
```

And the installer is similar to windows, when the "windows look like install finish" and it says everything's fine in the terminal says `core dumped` and i can't run `start_dtect` because it says the same error **`core dumped`**.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed it with the actions below:

```
sudo apt-get install csh
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://download.opendtect.org/relman/OpendTect_Installer_lux64.sh
sh OpendTect_Installer_lux64.sh
```

It was installed to *~/OpendTect*.

If I start it with *~/OpendTect/6.2.0/start_dtect* I get the same
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

But I can launch it by command (specifying library directory manually)

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/$USER/OpendTect/6.2.0/bin/lux64/Release \
/home/$USER/OpendTect/6.2.0/bin/lux64/Release/od_main
```

[image: OpendTect 6.2.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]

Note: I have never used this software, just installed to help you.

Answer (score 0):

@N0rbert gave usefull informations here.

OpendTect uses csh scripts to set up the necessary environment and these fail with a segfault. After digging a bit, I found that the segfault is caused by

```csh
eval `"${DTECT_APPL}/bin/mksethdir"`
```

Replacing this line in two scripts with `setenv HDIR lux64;  setenv binsubdir lux64` fix the issue.

In my case I have a `lux64` folder in `OpendTect/6.4.0/bin/`. If it's not the case for you, change `lux64` by whatever you have.

Here is the quick fix with sed :

```bsh
cd ~/OpendTect/6.4.0/bin # or wherever your opendtect folder is
sed -i 's/eval `"\$DTECT_APPL\/bin\/mksethdir"`/setenv HDIR lux64;  setenv binsubdir lux64/g' init_dtect
sed -i 's/eval `"\$DTECT_APPL\/bin\/mksethdir"`/setenv HDIR lux64;  setenv binsubdir lux64/g' od_exec
```

If anyone knows why `eval` is failing here, let us know.